# Run the code continuously until "Stop" is pressed

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I want to execute some code when I press a "Start" button and it have it continue running until I press "Stop".

However, with the following code once I press "Start", I can't press "Stop" anymore:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    if (ui->pushButton->text()=="Start") {
        ui->pushButton->setText("Stop");

        vec spectrum_sensed,Sn,sigma,alpha;
        mat ydata;
        condition=true;
        while (condition) {
            cvec uhd_samples = to_cvec(randn(Nsamples),randn(Nsamples));
            ydata=spectrum->dft(uhd_samples,Ndft,Nband);

            myplot->Plot_data(spectrum_sensed,Ndft);
        }
     }
     else {
         ui->pushButton->setText("Start");
         condition=false;
         myplot->clear_plot();
     }
}
```

Comment: Better code formatting, would improve readability.

Comment: Don't know qt but aren't you running on the UI thread? If so you should run your procedure on a separate thread.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow; please note that the best way to share problematic code is to *minimize* the examples. You are mentioning things like `cvec` and `spectrum->dft`... which are not standard in Qt and are libraries specific to what you're doing. But would you be able to show the lack of responsiveness with something much simpler *(such as a while loop that was just counting on forever? Wouldn't that do the same?)* See ["Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example"](http://sscce.org/) for important notes on this.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176488/application-processmessages-in-qt Without QApplication::processEvents(), your application has no chance to check the second click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt's GUI runs in a single thread, and if your code blocks that thread, things like mouse clicks won't ever get handled (because the thread is busy doing nothing but calculating your data), and so your GUI freezes up.

As for how to change your program so that doesn't happen, you have a few options:

1. You could just throw a call to qApp->processEvents() into your calculation loop.  That way Qt will get a chance to handle things like mouse clicks while you are calculating.  That's the easiest way to go, but it can bite you if you're not careful -- for example if you've set up some other code so that a mouse click causes your MainWindow to be deleted, then you're likely to crash because after processEvents() returns it find itself executing in the on_pushButton_clicked() method of a now-deleted MainWindow object(!).
2. You could spawn a separate thread (using the QThread object) and run your calculation loop there.  This is probably the most efficient approach, since on a multicore CPU it will let the GUI event loop run on one core while the calculations-loop simultaneously runs on another core, and so neither loop will slow the other one down.  Note that this approach only works if your calculation loop doesn't touch any of the Qt GUI stuff -- Qt's GUI widgets are meant to be accessed only by the GUI thread, and if you try to examine them or modify them from a different thread, bad things will happen.
3. You could "unwrap" your loop so that it's no longer a synchronous loop but rather more like a state machine:  That is, move the declarations of your calculation's state variables (spectrum_sensed, Sn, sigma, alpha, and ydata) out of the method, so that they are now member variables of the MainWindow class instead.  Then write a Slot method that just does one iteration of your while loop (or maybe a small number of iterations, depending on how long each iteration takes), and then (within a few dozen milliseconds) calls QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(TheCalculationSlotMethodName()) and returns.  That QTimer::singleShot() call will cause your calculation-slot-method to be called again on the next iteration of the Qt event loop, whereupon it can do a little bit more calculation.  When the user clicks the "Stop" button, just have your on_stopButton_Pushed() slot set a boolean or something so that your calculation-method will know not to call QTimer::singleShot() anymore.  I like this approach because there is little risk of race conditions or re-entrancy problems.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy! The command "qApp->processEvents()" solved it !
But please have you an idea how to plot spectrogram for my data?

Comment: @MkachakhMadridsita If you have more issues than stated in your original post, please ask a new question (as opposed to expanding the scope of your question in comments).  It's best when questions focus clearly on one issue at a time.  See my previous comment for what makes for a good [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  To expand Jeremy's warning, note that processEvents can bite you in pretty much any situation where [your code is not prepared to allow re-entrancy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25005590/#comment38881534_25005671).

Comment: It told me that i must wait for 5 days at least.

Comment: @MkachakhMadridsita That's probably a result of being a new user with some [negative scores](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4710965/mkachakh-madridsita?tab=questions).  If it's making you wait some time, take that time to go back over the questions and see what advice people were giving you in comments... and edit them to improve them.  *(You can win some new votes by doing so and also make your posts clearer and more useful to future users.)*  And five days is plenty of time to read [http://sscce.org/](http://sscce.org/) at least twice.  :-)